# How to perform validation check only if user input some value in the field in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm new in Laravel. I want to perform validation check only if user enter some value in the password text field. Otherwise, do not perform a validation check for the password field.

I searched for similar question but didn't find any satisfactory answer.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Update: Here is my code for validation**

```
public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [];

        $rules['profile_password'] ='sometimes|nullable|string|min:6|confirmed';
        $rules['profile_name'] = 'required|string|max:255';
        $rules['profile_email'] = 'required|string|email|max:255';
        $rules['profile_birth_day'] = 'date';
        $rules['profile_website'] = 'url';
        $rules['profile_facebook'] = 'url';
        $rules['profile_twitter'] = 'url';
        $rules['profile_google_plus'] = 'url';
        $rules['profile_you_tube'] = 'url';

        return $rules;
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation)?

Comment: Yes I did. I found something but that didn't work for me. I also went to laracast and found if statement with has() that also didn't work for me.

Comment: What validation you want ? Share your code also ?

Comment: Do you want to validate it for profile update ? Ithink If you just provided your try, your question would not get negative vote.

Comment: Yes I want to validate for profile update. I've added my code.

Comment: how you are storing users data?

Comment: user data like username, email, password in user table and rest of the information in profile table using one to one relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `required` rule

```
 "password" => "min:6 | max:12"
```

Password would be 6 to 12 in length only if password field is filled.

Answer (score -1):

You may try this code if you want to:

```
if(!empty($request->input('password'))){
  // perform the validation with password
} else{
  // perform the validation without password
}
```